# Microsoft Access 2016 - Record source does not exist

Tags: ms-access, printing, report

I encountered this error when I tried to open a Report.

```
The record source '~sq_dProduct Summary~sq_dOLEUnbound0' specified on this form or report does not exist.

The name of the recordsource may be misspelled, the recordsource was deleted or renamed, or the recordsource exists in a different database.

In the Form or Report's Design view or Layout view, display the property sheet by clicking the Properties button, and then set the RecordSource property to an existing table or query.
```

And it came up to be a blank "Print Preview" report. But when I right-click on the report and go to "Design View", there are data inside. I don't know what is wrong. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

This the naming convention Access uses to create queries behind the scenes when you set a RecordSource property using the builder button in design view of a form/report. When you press the builder button, you are presented with a QBE window (Query By Example). When you save the form or report, Access creates this query, hides it from the DB container, and uses it internally, although you see the actual SQL in the RecordSource property. This is why it appears to work in design view.

The problem is that the DB Engine can no longer find this "cached", hidden query.

I would:

- Copy the RecordSource property of the form or report to a text file.
- Drop the reports RecordSource Repair and compact the database
- Reopen the report, and paste in the RecordSource again.

If you are using subforms, combo boxes, list boxes, etc. that may also have a RecordSource property, you should do the same with them until you find the culprit. In other words, anywhere in the design of the report/form that you see a RecordSource property that has a SQL statement as the value for the RecordSource property.

A sure way to get around it is to create a normal query, then set the RecordSource property of all of the the form/report/controls to this permanent Access object.